Decoding OBD scanner live data labels
I am using a cheap OBD scanner with my prehistoric (2004) 2.0 petrol Hyundai Tucson.
When I am viewing the live data, I get some short data labels and some of them I don't understand what they mean. Is there some list of abbreviations that I can look up?
Most of the codes I don't understand probably have to do something with fuel system/fuel trim:

FUELSYS1 (CL) / FUELSYS2 (N/A)
SHRTFT3% (-45.3) / LONGFT3% (-39.8)
SHRTFTB1S1% (-5.5) / SHRTFTB1S2% (99.2)

In the parentheses are example values for each data label.
What perplexed me even more is that I can't make heads or tails of the SHRTFT3 / LONGFT3 data labels, since I also have SHRTFT1 / LONGFT1. My car is of course 4cyl, so only 1 bank I assume...
Also, I know that SHRTFT1 is most likely an average value, and individual sensor values are probably SHRTFTB1S1 and SHRTFTB1S2. But ...SHRTFTB1S2 is 99.2?!
It seems like I am missing something here...

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Disclaimer: This answer was written based on limited experience with OBD-II and the SAE J1979 standard and no experience with Hyundai cars. Take everything below with a grain of salt.
The labels come from the SAE J1979 standard. Copies of the current SAE J1979 standard are paywalled. You might find free copies of older revisions online. Check out the appendix on service $01 parameter IDs (PIDs) for the labels.
The Wikipedia article on ODB-II PIDs for Service $01 is a valuable source if your scanner can show PIDs. The Wikipedia article lists almost none of the labels.

FUELSYS1 (CL) = Fuel system 1 is in "closed loop" status
Closed loop means the ECU is using oxygen sensors as feedback for controlling the amount of injected fuel. The fuel system could be in "open loop" (i.e. NOT using oxygen sensors as feedback) e.g. when a minimum operating temperature has not been reached or in case of a sensor fault.

FUELSYS2 (N/A) = Fuel system 2 status not available
Your car has no fuel system 2. FUELSYS2 happens to be transmitted in the same OBD message as FUELSYS1 and I would speculate that your scanner does not filter irrelevant data.

SHRTFT1 (short-term fuel trim bank 1) is a value the ECU continuously computes based on input from a variety of sensors. It is not an average.

SHRTFT3 = Short-term fuel trim bank 3
You are right that your engine has no bank 3. A straight 4 engine has 1 bank only. Similar to FUELSYS2, SHRTFT3 happens to be transmitted in the same OBD message as SHRTFT1... Unless no SHRTFT1 value is displayed, I would ignore that.

LONGFT3 = Long-term fuel trim bank 3
LONGFT3 happens to be transmitted in the same OBD message as LONGFT1... Unless no LONGFT1 value is displayed, I would ignore that.

SHRTFTB1S1 = Short-term fuel trim bank 1 oxygen sensor 1
This is the pre-cat sensor. This is not a computed fuel trim (as in SHRTFTx), but an alternative way of describing the sensor voltage. SHRTFTB1S1 and O2SB1S1 (bank 1 oxygen sensor 1 voltage) are equivalent unless the oxygen sensor is not a conventional 0 to 1 V type.

SHRTFTB1S2 (99.2) = Short-term fuel trim bank 1 oxygen sensor 2
Sensor 2 is post-cat. 99.22 % (hexadecimal FF) is the maximum value which can be transmitted. According to SAE J1979, FF is used to indicate that this sensor is not used in calculation.



Thank you, this sheds some light! I didn't even know where to look up for these labels, I'll try to see if I can find that SAE standard. Also thanks for taking the time to explain the values, as well !
